# How do I setup a login page for mikrotik router?

Tags: router, login

I have a Mikrotik routerboad hAP lite and I want to setup a login page so that I can limit the number of users connecting to my hotspot, I know HTML and I can make the login page myself but I don't know where to upload the HTML file and how to redirect users to that page when they connect to the AP.

Comment: Search for "captive portal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also not an expert in mikrotik but i have used it for some my personal work.use the winbox and login to your router there you will find a tab in your left side contains menus in it select "Files" tab open it and here after you can simply yse the drag and drop to make your html page changes but don't forget to replace the deleted files it may cause your user in login page and also you can download your backup configuration files for your safety.